# How to automatically log time taken for all commands run by user in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time, syslog

I know that for logging time taken for executing a command/script in Linux we can put "time <command/script>".

However, I am looking for any method on how I can log all the commands entered by user in a bash shell and the time taken for each command without even entering time in front of each command by the user.

Basically in our organization, we have a need to monitor all the commands entered by users and fetch the time taken for certain commands on each machine. Is this even possible?

Comment: In short - NO. There isn't anything that logs the time of each command in a users shell. The shell history can be used to find out what was run, but not how long each command took.

Comment: I beg to differ. You could hack something together measuring the wall time by using `trap DEBUG` and `PROMPT_COMMAND`. However, malicious users will always find a way to circumvent your logging.

Comment: That might work for individual commands; if you string together pipelines you're out of luck ...

Comment: @tink I don't think so. Even though `DEBUG` runs before each single command, `PROMPT_COMMAND` runs only at each prompt, therefore after each prompt you can measure the time between the first `DEBUG` and the next prompt. The real pain begins with background jobs (`cmd &`).